# How can I make sure that the UWP protocol I assigned to my app is unique and what will happen if it's not?

Tags: c#, uwp, protocols

How can I make sure that the protocol I assigned to my UWP app is unique. Is it important that it's unique?

I can assigned whatever protocol during development. What will happen if that protocol is already being used by some other apps in the store and the user downloaded that app as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **LauncherOption's** **TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName** property. That it self helps your launcher figure out which specific app to launch.

Now let's say you want to activate your app by typing in the protocol in Run. Since you have more than one app installed, windows will pop up a dialog box to let you choose which app to launch.